# How do I convert hash keys to method names?

Tags: ruby

This is my hash:

```
tempData = {"a" => 100, "here" => 200, "c" => "hello"}
```

I need to access the hash keys as a method like:

```
tempData.a #100
tempData.here # 200
```

Comment: What's wrong with the normal accessor?

Comment: we can access in the traditional way, I am just curious about this :)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You could just wrap up your hash in an [OpenStruct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/classes/OpenStruct.html):

```
require 'ostruct'
tempData = {"a" => 100, "here" => 200, "c" => "hello"}
os = OpenStruct.new tempData
os.a #=> 100
os.here #=> 200
```

If you really really wanted to, you could also monkey-patch the `Hash` class, but I'd advise against that:

```
class Hash
  def method_missing(m, *args, &blk)
    fetch(m) { fetch(m.to_s) { super } }
  end
end

tempData = {"a" => 100, "here" => 200, "c" => "hello"}
tempData.a #=> 100
```

**Update:** In my [personal extensions library](https://rubygems.org/gems/shenanigans) I added a [Hash#to_ostruct](http://rubydoc.info/gems/shenanigans/1.0.3/frames) method. This will recursively convert a hash into an `OpenStruct` including all nested hashes.

Comment: I would add that the second solution is fine if you define a new class instead of overwriting the core Hash class.

Comment: @AdrienCoquio that is basically what OpenStruct is doing

Comment: An [interesting post](http://pullmonkey.com/2008/01/06/convert-a-ruby-hash-into-a-class-object/), which does the same thing, but needs to write a small class..

Comment: Thanks for the link. If you read the comments you'll see that the posts' author said that `OpenStruct` handles all of his initial implementation, but not nested hashes as the version he posted in the comments.

Comment: @MichaelKohl..yes..u r right..I used his version of nested hash, in a project where there was a serialized column (which converts to a nested hash in Ruby)and needed it for my Rails form elements having (object, method) syntax..

Answer (score 22):

There is another way to do this.

`JSON.parse(tempData.to_json, object_class: OpenStruct)`

that will give object
`#<OpenStruct a=100, here=200, c="hello">`

In this way nested `hash` also will be converted to `OpenStruct Object`

```
tempData = {a: { b: { c: 3}}, foo: 200, msg: 'test msg'}
obj = JSON.parse(tempData.to_json, object_class: OpenStruct)
```

Now we are able to call

```
obj.a.b.c # 3
obj.foo # 200
obj.msg # 'test msg'
```

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: This is quite useful to load test data stored as json into object stubs - instead of tempData.to_json the JSON is loaded from a file.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, if it’s just a small script it might be more convenient to just extend `Hash` itself

```
class Hash
  def method_missing sym,*
    fetch(sym){fetch(sym.to_s){super}}
  end
end
```

`method_missing` is a magic method that is called whenever your code tries to call a method that does not exist. Ruby will intercept the failing call at run time and let you handle it so your program can recover gracefully. The implementation above tries to access the hash using the method name as a symbol, the using the method name as a string, and eventually fails with Ruby's built-in method missing error.

> **NB** for a more complex script, where adding this behavior might break other third-party gems, you might alternatively use a module
>   and extend each instance
>
> ```
> module H
>   def method_missing sym,*
>     fetch(sym){fetch(sym.to_s){super}}
>   end
> end
>
> the = { answer: 42 }
> the.extend(H)
> the.answer # => 42
> ```
>
> and for greater convenience you can even propagate the module down to
>   nested hashes
>
> ```
> module H
>   def method_missing sym,*
>     r = fetch(sym){fetch(sym.to_s){super}}
>     Hash === r ? r.extend(H) : r
>   end
> end 
>
> the = { answer: { is: 42 } }
> the.extend(H)
> the.answer.is # => 42
> ```

Comment: This is fine as long as your keys aren't messages to which the native Hash already responds.  For instance, try: `the = { answer: { display: 42 } }`

Answer (score 3):

If the hash is inside a module, you can define methods on that module (or class) dynamically using `define_method`. For example:

```
module Version
  module_function

  HASH = { 
    major: 1,
    minor: 2,
    patch: 3,
  }

  HASH.each do |name, value|
    define_method(name) do
      return value
    end
  end
end
```

This will define a `Version` module with `major`, `minor`, and `patch` methods that return 1, 2, and 3, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

you can extend the Hash class in the following way.

```
class Hash
      # return nil whenever the key doesn't exist
      def method_missing(m, *opts)
        if self.has_key?(m.to_s)
          return self[m.to_s]
        elsif self.has_key?(m.to_sym)
          return self[m.to_sym]
        end
        return nil

        # comment out above line and replace with line below if you want to return an error
        # super
      end
end
```