# Deep delete from Ruby hash by dotted path

Tags: ruby

Given such hash with nested hashes in Ruby (deep may vary):

```
hash = {"status_message"=>
         { "destination_does_not_exist"=>
           {"message_header"    => "Zielordner existiert nicht",
            "message_body"      => "Der Zielordner für das Backup existiert nicht mehr.",
            "corrective_action" => "Erstellen Sie den Zielordner."
           }
         }
       }
```

How can I delete key and all its children values using simple "dotted" notation?
Something like:

```
path = "status_message.destination_does_not_exist.message_header"
hash.delete!(path)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423484/how-do-i-convert-hash-keys-to-method-names

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
path = path.split '.'
leaf = path.pop

path.inject(hash) {|h, el| h[el]}.delete leaf
```

Comment: Good catch, thanks. I just learning ruby, so didn't recognise this as a simple tree.

Comment: Yossi, may be there is some information around operating with trees using Ruby? How to represent them using hashes and so on/

Comment: Never seen any resources on that, sorry.