# Hash, keys, and parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I would like the code to pull information from the cart api and store it in a hash with simple keys, then iterate over the hash to make new html elements as needed per item. Every item that I need to pull has the following: `id`, `Name`, and `Price`.

```
products.each do |product|
  @product_card = [
      {
          :id => "#{product['product_id']}",
          :name => "#{product['name']}",
          :price => "#{product['price']}"
      }
  ]
```

I want to store the information in a hash so I can iterate over the info on the fly like so:

```
<% @product_card.each do |Need help here, Need help here| %>
<html p><% :id %></html p>
<html p><% :name %></html p>
<html p><% :price %></html p>
```

I stay hopeful for any feedback you can offer.

Comment: This seems like what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423484/how-do-i-convert-hash-keys-to-method-names

Comment: It's not very clear from this what the problem is - what does this produce and how does it differ from your expectations ?

Comment: @FrederickCheung yeah, I was trying to express what I want but I can see how it can be unclear.  what I would like is to store item information in a hash and call it via hash.name hash.price.

Comment: Make it something the reader can actually do something with, for example what data does this api return? What are the contents of @product_card at the end?

Comment: @FrederickCheung I just made my edit, after thinking about this over night.

Comment: @FrederickCheung I am sure the question has been on stackOver but the link you gave is simply not what I wish to do. Thanks for the help any ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do something like

```
@product_card = {}
products.each do |product|
  @product_card[product['name']] = client.call('call' ,session_id ,"product.info#{product['id']}")
end
```

then at the end @product_card is hash where the keys are names and the values are whatever this api returns, apparently hashes, so when you do

```
<% @product_card.each do |key, data | %>
```

`key` will be the name and `data` the return value from the api (these are arbitrary names). Assuming the api does indeed return hashes you'd want

```
<%= data['price'] %>
```

and so on, inside the each loop

Comment: when I do 
      @product_card[product['name']] = product['product_id']
 this does not return any value. <%= data['name'] %> I know the hash must have the data do to the loop making product cards. I just need that data. One more thing how would I add more "keys" to the hash above @product_card

Comment: Then perhaps the data isn't as you expected it (symbol vs string keys is a common one) inspect the return value from the api and change accordingly. You add keys to a hash by doing hash[key] = value

Comment: So I would need something like product_a[:name = 'foo', :id = 'foo1', :price=19.99]

Comment: No, you'd need 3 separate assignments. You might also want try a basic ruby syntax guide as it would cover a lot of this sort of thing.

Comment: you're 100% correct, the main issue here is my lack of understanding the syntax and the way it works. I can not help but dive in rails. Thanks again for the information!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a `Struct`. Adds a bit of overhead, but makes your intention crystal clear.

```
ProductCard = Struct.new(:id, :name, :price)

@product_cards = products.map do |product|
  ProductCard.new("#{product['product_id']}", "#{product['name']}", "#{product['price']}")
end
```

This gives you an array of `ProductCards` which you can iterate over and call `.id`, `.name`, `.price`.

Alternative using `OpenStruct` which does not require declaring a `ProductCard` constant:

```
@product_cards = products.map do |product|
  OpenStruct.new(id: "#{product['product_id']}", name: "#{product['name']}", price: "#{product['price']}")
end
```

Comment: Struct doesn't support that form of initialiser does it (I wish it did) ?

Comment: @FrederickCheung: It does, unless I'm reading http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Struct.html wrong.

Comment: That only shows passing comma separated values not hash / keyword arg style as you have shown

Comment: Looks like that's more of an `OpenStruct` thing.

Comment: How would I iterate over the OpenStruct? also the products.each loop is what I use to get item from the api and store in the hash.